# How to pivot value of JSON in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an original DataFrame that contain a list of JSON in each record

Here is an example of the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
d = [{
    'id': 'abcd1234',
    'property_name':'a',
    'timestamp':'2021:12:10',
    'raw_data': [
        {
        'key1':'value1',
        'key2':'value2'
    },
    {
        'key3':'value3',
        'key4':'value4'
    }]
    
},
{   'id':'efgh5678',
    'property_name':'b',
    'timestamp':'2021:12:12',
    'raw_data': [{
        'key5':'value5',
        'key6':'value6'
    }]
}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Here is the output of DataFrame

```
id  property_name   timestamp   raw_data
0   abcd1234    a   2021:12:10  [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}]
1   efgh5678    b   2021:12:12  [{'key5': 'value5', 'key6': 'value6'}]
```

Now, I want to transform this DataFrame with the following condition,

1. Pivot the keys of JSON as a column and value of the JSON as a value
2. Have some prefix of the columns name based on 'property_name' field
3. For a record with absence value, make it NULL

Here is a desired final DataFrame

```
id  property_name   timestamp   a_key1  a_key2  a_key3  a_key4  b_key5  b_key6
0   abcd1234    a   2021:12:10  value1  value2  value3  value4  NaN     NaN
1   efgh5678    b   2021:12:12  NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN    value5  value6
```

So far, I have succeeded it with for loop in each record which is not quite efficient way to achieve since the DataFrame is expected to grow exponentially. Anyway to make this function in the efficient way?

Ps1. The following is the coded that I am using

```
raw_data = pd.DataFrame()
for idx,val in df["raw_data"].iteritems():
    the_list = json.loads(val)
    temp = pd.DataFrame(the_list, index=[idx]*len(the_list))
    temp['key'] = stg1.loc[idx, 'raw_data'] + '_' + temp['key']
    raw_data = pd.concat([raw_data,temp], axis=0)

raw_data = raw_data.set_index("property_name",append=True).unstack()
raw_data.columns = raw_data.columns.droplevel(0)
final = df[['uid', 'property_name', 'timestamp']].join(raw_data)
```

Ps2. Apologize for the unclear DataFrame format. This is the first time I post on Stack overflow and I don't figure out how to post pretty format of DataFrame.

Comment: I renamed `dict` to `d`. Avoid using builtin as variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first modify the dicts in "raw_data" to include the property names in the keys. Then `set_index` with the column names other than "raw_data", then `explode` the "raw_data" column. Then convert the resulting Series to a DataFrame, `groupby` + `first` to get a single row for each property name.

```
df['raw_data'] = [[{f'{pn}_{k}': v for k,v in d.items()} for d in lst] for pn, lst in zip(df['property_name'], df['raw_data'])]
s = df.set_index(df.columns.drop('raw_data').tolist())['raw_data'].explode()
out = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index).groupby(level=[0,1,2]).first().reset_index().fillna(np.nan)
```

Output:

```
         id property_name   timestamp  a_key1  a_key2  a_key3  a_key4  b_key5   b_key6
0  abcd1234             a  2021:12:10  value1  value2  value3  value4     NaN      NaN
1  efgh5678             b  2021:12:12     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  value5   value6
```

Comment: d = [{
    'id': 'abcd1234',
    'property_name':'a',
    'timestamp':'2021:12:10',
    'raw_data': [
        {
        'key':'key1',
        'value':'value1'
    },
    {
        'key':'key2',
        'value':'value2'
    }]
    
},
{   'id':'efgh5678',
    'property_name':'b',
    'timestamp':'2021:12:12',
    'raw_data': [{
        'key':'key3',
        'value':'value3'
    }]
    }]

Sorry, if I change dictionary as above (name of the key is the value of 'key' and the same for value), how should I change your code to get the DataFrame I want?